# Configure Unit Testing using Karma and Jasmine and code coverage using istanbul for an angular 2 app

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, istanbul, karma-coverage, karma-systemjs

Please find the link to the bitbucket repo below

https://bitbucket.org/abhinav-cleo/harmonyangular2project

its a public repo.

the app is written using angular 2 and typescript. all the components are inside the app folder which are to be unit tested using karma and Jasmine and also code coverage has to be configured as well using istanbul. Or another test runners and unit testing and code coverage frameworks works as well for example mocha and karma-coverage.

I have googled up and in all blogs and tutorials i find the author is using a file called karma-shim.js along with the karma.conf.js. i have tried to configure it the same way as described (off course modified the paths as per my requirements)

but i am getting

> Error TS1110 Build: Type expected

when i checked in details the configurations of the angular2 app itself is different from what i have...
configurations are in files with **.config.js** suffix.

Can anyone please guide me about how to setup the unit testing for this app,

any help or advice is appreciated.

let me know if you need any further information from me. Or if i missed anything...

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little broad and I can't see your karma files in the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing,...
my mistake. this is the correct repo
https://bitbucket.org/abhinav-cleo/harmonyapp in this repo the system and testing works. what i am trying to achieve is setup the same testing environment as harmonyApp repo in harmonyangular2project repo